Ошибка при загрузке картинки из файла в SFML
Начал делать игру Arkanoid на С++ на SFML. Хотел загрузить картинку названия игры, но при попытке это сделать, возникает Debug error! abort() has been called.
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "Arkanoid", sf::Style::Fullscreen);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    sf::Texture logoTexture;
    sf::Sprite logo;

    if (!logoTexture.loadFromFile("Assets/ArkanoidLogo.png"));
    {
        throw "Could not load ArkanoidLogo.png!"; // <- Здесь возникает ошибка
    }

    logo.setTexture(logoTexture);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed || event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear();

        window.draw(logo);

        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}


Наверное у вас текущая директория не там, где вы думаете. Напечатайте std::filesystem::current_path() на пробу.

Кидая исключение, вы его не ловите и никак не обрабатываете, поэтому программа завершается нештатно. Кроме того, стоит кидать исключения, наследуемые от std::exception. Ну а чтоб файлы грузились, следует формировать для них абсолютный путь.

Проверь путь до картинки, в VS кстати если путь указан верно то при наведении на него - отобразит само изображение.
Примерно так:


VS покажет картинку, если сможет найти ее в проекте по этому пути, а не если путь указан верно.

К чему это уточнение? Лишний раз придраться?
Вы кладёте файлы проекта вне проекта? Так получается?

К тому, что этот ответ никак не поможет решить описанную в вопросе проблему.
